# Running python Unittest in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, devops, python-unittest

I am a new programmer. I have a simple calculator python code which i want to deploy using Jenkins pipeline.

There is a python unittest file in my git repo named "unit-test". I tried to execute unit test as mentioned in the **stage(test)**, but it is not working.

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
            python setup.py nosetests --with-xunit
            nosetests unit-test.py
```

Can someone please help me fix the issue.

My github repo url: https://github.com/Tasfiq23/Devops_assessment_2.git/

Answer (score 4):

I have re-created your pipeline in Jenkins and it got success.

**Pipeline Script**

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage ('GIT Checkout'){
        steps {
            git changelog: false, poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/Tasfiq23/Devops_assessment_2.git'
        }
    }
    
    stage('build') {
  steps {
    sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
  }
}
    stage ('Test'){
        steps {
            sh 'python unit-test.py'
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]